# How to setup Products in Magento CE, if owner wants to sell some gift boxes along with the products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.6

Just stuck while doing setup for Magento products. How am I supposed to create product and associate some multiple options for Gift boxes.

So that, when a customer selects a product, a number of gift boxes will be displayed (optional for customer).

I am confused between group products and bundle products.

which one would be better to do so? Please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see about the cross-sells.This can fulfill your requirement. Have a look to the below link for general overview.

[Cross-sells](http://inchoo.net/magento/related-products-up-sells-cross-sells-in-magento/)

If you want to choose the product type among above two, I think you should go with Bundle product. But may not fulfill your requirement. Have better understanding about these product types and choose the best according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi aton, both are simple products, and want to show on product description page when customer is clicking on add to qty, it will show box options. 

Cross sells won't help me on this.

Bundle product is ok, but I little bit confused.

Comment: What is your confusion? I think you have to have look on the document related to bundle product and that's it.